# Wrong PHP date() output in wamp server

Tags: php, wampserver

The problem is that date('r') returns wrong time for my timezone.

php.ini timezone setting:
date.timezone = Europe/Kiev

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev') in my script solves the problem.

So what's wrong with WAMP?

Comment: the setting in php.ini actually doesn't work before wampserver2.2, but it has been fixed in wampserver2.4 now

Comment: restart the wamp server after you edit the configurations in `php.ini` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the Timezone for PHP in the php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file)

Answer (score 9):

I suggest always using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) from script

e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
```

or

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Kiev');
```

...to avoid PHP guessing timezone.

It comes handy when you transfer code to different server(s), for example, outside of Ukraine. This line should help you to avoid unexpected (wrong) results if `date.timezone` is not set in `php.ini` or its setting is incorrect. It's also handy when you can't access and/or modify `php.ini` (shared hosting).

Also, be sure that you've not used `;` at the and of line in `php.ini`.

Restart server after changing `php.ini`.

Answer (score 6):

Edit `php.ini` and restart Apache:

- left click to **WampServer in tray icon**
- open `php.ini` (go to **PHP -> php.ini**)
- set new `date.timezone` value

```
    ;date.timezone = UTC 
    date.timezone = Europe/Kiev
```

- restart Apache ( go to **Apache -> Service -> Restart Service** )
- check value of `date.timezone` by `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 3):

You need to reload the configuration / restart the server after editing your php.ini file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I restarted my server several times.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of `date_default_timezone_get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), the [`date.timezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) configuration option can be overridden by setting the `TZ` environement variable (which, in turn, can be overridden by calling [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)). From your description, I suspect that the `TZ` environement veriable is set.

Answer (score 1):

by default it shows GMT time you can change for your region with following code

```
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");//set you countary name from below timezone list
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());//now it will show "Asia/Bangkok" or your date time
```

List of Supported Timezones
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question.
If you are using a PHP framework, you might want to check the config file of the framework. For example in Laravel, open the `config/app.php` and you will find timezone there. Set it to your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your php.ini with maybe notepad++, sublime text...
2. Add this line to the file: date.timezone = "X" Where X is the your time-zone of wish. Get a list of supported timezones here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

... That should do it.
3. Restart your server