# Time zone in wamp

Tags: php, datetime

I am using wamp in window 8 and in this i am using the time zone Asia/Calcutta but the problem is that when i tried to get the current date and time then it gives me one day after date 
for ex: today is 28 june it gives me 29 june i check that my default time zone is Asia/Calcutta

Code is

```
$currentDate = strtotime("now");    
$starttime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDate);
```

Then it gives me the out put:
2014-06-29 04:17:02

I am not able to get this and i have also changed the php.in

Comment: What is your system date?

Comment: its is 6/28/2014 3:59 PM

Comment: I have added in the wamp >> php >> php.in >> date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta;

And i tried on linux it work fine but in window its not working

Comment: What version of WAMP are you using? Have a read of this and see if anything works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753699/wrong-php-date-output-in-wamp-server

Comment: Still, does explicitly stating the timezone using DateTimeZone or in your script using ini_set give you the correct result?

Comment: Yup i have seen the above link and i m using wamp 2.3

Comment: i my php info its showing timezone Asia/Calcutta

Comment: I got this result
C:\Users\Technicus Shubham>date /T && time /T && tzutil /g
Sat 06/28/2014
04:31 PM
Pacific Standard Time

Comment: Have you tried changeing the timezone to `Asia/Kolkata`? `Asia/Calcutta`seems to be obsolete by some comments

Comment: no it is not working @Rangad i have changed the same in my php.in and

Comment: Well, was my best guess since the timezone identifier is not present in PHP 5.3 or later anymore: http://3v4l.org/nhZZ0

Comment: And its is working in LAMP in linux

Comment: But how i will correct the same in wamp

Comment: There are two php.ini configuration files, one for Apache, and one for the CLI (command-line interface). Make sure you have configured the one that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DateTime` class instead

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The printed date will be in the default timezone, based on `php.ini` or system default. To set a specific timezone, do this:

```
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your php.ini with maybe notepad++, sublime text...
2. Add this line to the file: date.timezone = "X" Where X is the your time-zone of wish. Get a list of supported timezones here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

... That should do it.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server