# Setting the Timezone for PHP in the php.ini file

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to change the default PHP timezone to `Asia/Calcutta` by accessing the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file and changing

```ini
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```

to

```ini
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Asia/Calcutta"
```

However, when I try to view current timezone under `phpinfo()`, the timezone follows the `Europe/Berlin` timezone.

I have tried stopping and restarting the Apache server, but that didn't seem to have changed the settings.

Is there something I'm missing in the process?

PS: I'm using PHP 5.6.8 currently under XAMPP.

Comment: Have you tried it without the quote marks? `date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta` ... and make sure it's not overridden anywhere .

Comment: @CD001 Yes, I have tried without the quote marks as well. That didn't work either.

Comment: You are trying to change the timezone for your web server processes, but you are editing the CLI php.ini file (`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`) which will change it only when running PHP from the terminal.

Comment: It's recommended to restart your web server to reload PHP.ini settings.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I tried all the other possible solutions posted, but none of them helped. This is what helped me save my timezone settings:

1) Go to your `phpinfo()` page and search for `Loaded Configuration File` and open the `php.ini` file mentioned under that section.

2) Change the default timezone settings by adding your new timezone by modifying this line: `date.timezone=Asia/Kolkata`.

3) Save the `php.ini` file and stop the Apache server.

4) Restart the Apache server. The timezone settings should now be modified.

Comment: Some examples show the value in quotes like "Asia/Kolkata" and others do not like the above. Are both acceptable?

Comment: like what @AnthonyPetrillo asked, are both acceptable ? I can't get mine to work

Comment: Like @namal has answered above, you need to set the strings as defined in [timezones list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), then see the results reflected by`php -r 'phpinfo();'`

Answer (score 15):

You can change it in the code without touching the ini file, at the beginning of your code add:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta')
```

Comment: Would that change the global time settings for my PHP installation?

Comment: it'll change this for the global current run, if you add this line and then do
`new DateTime('now')` at any place of your code, it will generate it with the timezone you set in the `date_default_timezone_set`  
@ManasChaturvedi

Comment: ive tried so many diff ways and this is the only way thats worked

Comment: I tried many different ways as well on XAMPP for windows to no avail. This was the only way that worked for me.

Comment: Auto-prepend a script with date_default_timezone_set to make it global.

Answer (score 10):

You are changing the wrong file. The file `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is used by cli - command line interface. Don't forget to restart your web-server after you update the right one: `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

File locations for different OS:

```
OS                               ->  Location

windows(With Xampp Installation) -> /xampp/php/php.in 

Mac OSX                          -> /private/etc/php.ini

Linux                            -> /etc/php.ini

                                 -> /usr/bin/php5/bin/php.ini

                                 -> /etc/php/php.ini

                                 -> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: *The file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini is used by cli* ... well spotted :)

Comment: I have Ubuntu installed, and I don't seem to have the following files:  `/etc/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Infact, I don't seem to have a `apache2` folder inside the `php5` folder at all. I do have a `cgi` folder though, and can access the `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini`.

Comment: you can view used php.ini files by running scipt with `phpinfo();` function from your browser.

Comment: any luck with setting timezone?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and discovered that there are two date.timezone statements in php.ini in my version of XAMPP out of the box.  The first statement one is commented out, but the second one is set to Europe/Berlin. So you if you edit your php.ini and search for timezone and logically uncomment the first statement with your time zone, the second statement overrides that back to Europe/Berlin.

Answer (score 2):

- `phpinfo()` was returning `Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini`.
- My `date.timezone` changes were not taking effect after updating the above and restarting `php-fpm` (`sudo systemctl reload php5.6-fpm.service`).
- `phpinfo()` also has an `Additional .ini files parsed` section, which contained `/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/timezone.ini`.
- After updating the `timezone.ini` file (`date.timezone = "America/New_York"`) and restarting `php-fpm` (as above), `phpinfo()` correctly returned `date.timezone => America/New_York => America/New_York`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, running `systemctl restart php-fpm` after editing the /etc/php-ini file solved the problem.

Comment: On Debian based systems with the PHP maintainer's repository, it is php8.3-fpm.service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel, you should change the Laravel timezone configuration.

My case Laravel 6. Edit /config/app.php file and change this line

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

to

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
```

then edit .env file. add your timezone ([timezone list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php))

```
APP_TIMEZONE='America/New_York'
```

clear configurations

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you 're serious about web developping get a VM going(Virtual Box + Vagrant).
2. With XAMPP be careful. Sometimes there's more than 1 php.ini file and you might be editing the wrong one. To edit the real one, access it from the XAMPP control panel.
3. You can use the a function in your code: date_default_timezone_set();

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration in your system.

In my case, it was "**Ubuntu**"

```
sudo cat /etc/timezone Asia/Kolkata
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case,
Centos 8, DirectAdmin, Openlitespeed, php 7 (lsphp server must run with Openlitespeed)

1. Go to DirectAdmin (with admin/root password) -> CustomBuild - > SETTINGS - >
   Options -> PHP Settings -> php_timezone -> input your time zone and save
   Time zoze is list here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
2. return CustomBuild -Build -> select PHP, and click build!
3. Waite 10 minute for amazing...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing had worked for me, I'm using FPM.

Found a file called `www.conf` inside `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d` , edited `php_admin_value[date.timezone]` value, restarted FPM with `sudo service php8.2-fpm` and it worked.

I'm using Vultr, hope this answer will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This error is very common. Many people think it is along these lines:
Do the following. Search this line `date.timezone: Europe/Berlin` and change to your zone. Typically you will find it like this:

```
[Session]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Date]
date.timezone=Europe/Berlin

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile=On
mysql.allow_persistent=On
```

Answer (score 0):

0

You need only set defaul time zone in your php file. Make this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
```

Is a good programming practice always specify the timezone for your projects in php script. So if you to change server, your code doesn't break.

```
date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONE OF YOUR PROJECT);
```

If is important expose timezone for users, make with javascript