# PHP my timezone is no setting up in PHP.ini File in xampp

Tags: php, apache, date, datetime, xampp

I've xampp installed on my Local PC.
But I've a Problem in my Timezone. PHP date shows my Date & Time `02/11/2018 05:26:18`. but my PC Time is `02/11/2018 09:26:18`. My Timezone is Asia/Karachi. I've Changed My Timezone in php.ini and My Timezone in php.ini Look like this

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Asia/Karachi"
```

I've also changed the right php.ini file according to phpinfo.
I've restarted my Server many times but still getting the same timezone .
My PHP version is `7.1.10`

Comment: Does `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi")` works in your script ?

Comment: Yes it works @Syscall

Comment: Ok. Maybe you've not changed the right php.ini. Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file ?

Comment: Yes i read it .
and i've this path in phpinfo "C:\xampp\php\php.ini" and i changed the same file @Syscall

Comment: but it's still showing me the Europe/Berlin Timezone in phpinfo

Comment: Oh. there was a second date.timezone in that file
and now that works fine . . . 

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Session]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Date]
date.timezone=Asia/Karachi
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile=On
mysql.allow_persistent=On
mysql.cache_size=2000
mysql.max_persistent=-1
mysql.max_link=-1

Comment: So, you could add an awser and mark it to accepted for futur users. Thanks.

Comment: How ? i'm new to stackoverflow . . .  give me an instruction link for that

Comment: Write the anwser of your question in the textbox below. Then check the green check on the left of the anwser after submitted it. Here is the link for how to accept : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: There is a second `date.timezone` in php.ini
<br>
In my case, it is in line 1972 under `[ffi]` block

Comment: This is the answer, or at least the other half. There are TWO locations to change: One under [date] and the other under [ffi]. Don't forget to restart the Apache server after saving the changes. Also, there can be two php.ini files. In my case Apache pointed to the incorrect one, as I needed to change the one under htdocs/dashboard. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As @Shaida Muhammad suggested in comments to the question, there seems to be a second date.timezone in php.ini for xampp. You can safely remove/comment the second date.timezone.

```
[Date]
date.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, instead of going everywhere else i just clicked on Apache config button in xampp control panel and clicked on php.ini.

There is a second timezone line in that file go and search for it you will find your solution there.

```
[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Session]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Date]
date.timezone=Asia/Karachi
[MySQL]
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31628373)

Answer (score 0):

You need only set defaul time zone in your php file. Make this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
```

Is a good programming practice always specify the timezone for your projects in php script. So if you to change server, your code doesn't break.

```
date_default_timezone_set(*TIMEZONE OF YOUR PROJECT*);
```

If is important expose timezone for users, make with javascript