# How to fix date format in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have a problem to set my date format using `PHPExcel` on `Codeigniter`

I already have controller and model and view that you can access

Model: `http://sistempintar.com/file/LingkunganModel.txt`

Controller: `http://sistempintar.com/file/Lingkungan.txt`

View: `http://sistempintar.com/file/form.txt`

I make a preview before import to a database, but an error that says

> "A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
>
> Filename: Shared/Date.php
>
> Line Number: 167
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php
>   Line: 167 Function: date_create
>
> File:
>   /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php
>   Line: 454 Function: ExcelToPHPObject
>
> File:
>   /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php
>   Line: 607 Function: _formatAsDate
>
> File:
>   /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php
>   Line: 2493 Function: toFormattedString
>
> File:
>   /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php
>   Line: 2556 Function: rangeToArray
>
> File:
>   /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/application/controllers/Lingkungan.php
>   Line: 51 Function: toArray
>
> File: /home/u4502442/public_html/sistempintar/demo/proyek/index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once"

and this is my date.php: http://sistempintar.com/file/date.txt

this is the picture that shows error :

```
http://sistempintar.com/file/format_database.png
```

I don't' know what is wrong, please help

Comment: [In your php.ini config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32227023/61795), or [before you start calling](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) your date functions `set date.timezone to select your timezone` as per the error message.

Comment: on my date.php you mean ?

Comment: even i set date.timezone to my timezone, the error still same

Comment: okay, what error are you trying to fix? the date error or the function error?

Comment: When process to input from excel (after preview) to database, there are error that the dates on database will 0000-00-00, but when i try it 121212, on database it will be 2012/12/12

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your PHP timezone settings. In your php.ini file, look for this line:
 *date.timezone =* 
and set it to your timezone. 
You can find a list of supported Timezones here: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is that, we have to convert the format of date from date to number using option Format Cells so our date will display some kind of numeric data on the cell.

This is because excel use a simple number formatting to read dates like 1/1/1900 = 1.00 and 16/1/2012 = 40924.00. So whenever we have to upload dates using excel we have to convert it into number and then upload it and just before the insert query of database we use a function which is listed below to convert the number format into date format which support by database.

```
function excel_number_to_date($num)

{

$num=$num-25570; //this is because php date function work only for date after 1/1/1970

return addday(‘1970/01/02’,$num);

}
```

The static no. 25570 denoted a date of 1/1/1970. Because while we upload data in MySQL than it will not read date which is older than 1/1/1970. Thants why I have to subtract this particular no. IT totally depends on type of database and addday function is listed below.

```
function addday($dat,$days) //$date will be in YYYY/mm/dd format

{

$dat=str_replace(“/”,”-“,$dat);

$dat=date(“Y-m-d”,strtotime($dat));

return date(“Y-m-d”,strtotime($days.’ days’,strtotime($dat)));

}
```

Comment: Where can i put that code ? Ya yaa i got it, because when i input to database like 14/14/1800 no problem

Comment: because on database, date wil be 0000-00-00, please help me

Comment: `//this is because php date function work only for date after 1/1/1970` hasn't been correct since the early days of PHP5, and even then only on Windows

Comment: so, should i change 1970 to 1900 ? just it?

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

You can try this line of code to set your timezone in CodeIgniter.

You can get a list of time zones to use from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: it's useless, i already set to my timezone, and doesn't give anything