# Date function time in hour always returning 1 php

Tags: php, datetime, localhost

when I call Date("H")

```
<?php echo Date("H"); ?>
```

it displays 01 but the current time is 9:45 AM, its supposed to display 09 right?

*output:*

[image]

*current time :*

[image]

I tried to restart service and also restart the computer but its still 01

Comment: check what your timezone setting is in your `.ini` file(s). You may need to set it to (your) local time. This happened to me before when installing PHP on a local machine I once had.

Comment: is it the date.timezone = "UTC"

Comment: See this Q&A here on Stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file - I think it would be a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your timezone is wrong, try to set this before your code:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Fortaleza');
```

Change 'America/Fortaleza' to your timezone.

You can set it in php.ini too:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/Fortaleza"
```