# Change timezone in shopware 6?

Tags: timezone, shopware

My current timezone is "Europe/Berlin". I want to change it to 'Asia/Calcutta' how to change timezone in shopware 6? Which file do I want to change?

Answer (score 0):

This should be part of your php environment, just make sure, that PHP uses the timezone you need.

Comment: Default timezone, $_COOKIE['timezone'], $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'], HTTP_COOKIE in PHPinfo is "Asia/Calcutta". But the system shows "Europe/Berlin".

Comment: Shopware saves every timestamp in utc - only the frontend/administration calculates the timestamp based on the clients timezone. So if your client uses Europe/Berlin, every time will be Europe/Berlin. When you are located in Asia, it should be Asia/Calcutta.

Comment: Shopware 6 is running on my local machine via docker.

In which file I can change the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a c-panel, pleskpanel or some alternative, you can change it through it or from php settings $_COOKIE['timezone'], $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'], HTTP_COOKIE

The timezone is taken as the default timezone of the server.

Please see this link 
[Setting the Timezone for PHP in the php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file)

Answer (score 0):

I believed that you can change the timezone in public/index.php

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = new HttpKernel($appEnv, $debug, $classLoader);
date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Calcutta' );
$result = $kernel->handle($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

For docker you edit the `docker-compose.yml` file like so:

```yaml
environment:
  - TZ=Asia/Calcutta
```

In a Docker file:

```
ENV TZ="Asia/Calcutta"
```

or if you start docker from command line:

```bash
docker run -it -e TZ="Asia/Calcutta"
```