# PHP new DateTime() throws Invalid date.timezone value

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

This script:

```
<?php
    $dateTime = new DateTime();
?>
```

Throws this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Invalid date.timezone value 'America/Argentia/Buenos_Aires', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in /var/www/html/date.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/date.php(2): DateTime->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/date.php on line 2
```

Pay attention to the timezone "Argentia", looks like a typo, but I do not know WHERE it's configured.

What I already try:

- I edited the timezone in php.in: `date.timezone = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"` and restart apache2 service.
- I checked the server timezone (that's ok):

```
# timedatectl | grep "Time zone"
Time zone: America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires (-03, -0300)
```

Note:
Adding the following line at the start of the script
`date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");`
The problem "is solved", but I am looking for a general solution to the problem.

System info:
Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.4

Thanks!

Comment: The default timezone is configured by the `data.timezone` entry in PHP.INI. You say you've edited that, so that is your general solution. If that didn't fix the problem are you sure you've edited the right copy of PHP.INI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the Timezone for PHP in the php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file)

Comment: **phpinfo() shows me:**
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
date.timezone America/Argentia/Buenos_Aires America/Argentia/Buenos_Aires

**And when edit this file, I have:**
date.timezone = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"

I'm restarting Apache using: sudo service apache2 restart

I don't know what's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions posted, but they didn't work for me. I wrote a phpinfo() page to shows me the location of the php.ini file. Then, I edited it to set a new date.timezone, and restarted the server, the change hasn't impact.

This is what helped me to fix the wrong timezone:

1. I find the typo wrong timezone under the php folder, using:

```
grep -rl "Argentia" /etc/php
```

2. Command's output:

```
/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/Custom.ini
```

3. So, I edit the finded file and modify the timezone.
4. Restart the apache2 services, and it works!