# PHP date function stuck at 11 minutes

Tags: php, date, web, time

When I run this code:

```php
$time = time();
echo "$time<br>";
echo date("H:m \a\\t d/m/Y", $time);
```

It echos: 
1668166632 
11:11 at 11/11/2022

But the expected result is:

1668166632 
12:37 at 11/11/2022

This happens until the next hour which it changes to 12:11.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Date format `m` is for months, `i` is for minutes.

Comment: I totally forgot! Thank you.

Comment: (The one hour difference comes probably from not selecting your desired timezone: [Setting the Timezone for PHP in the php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue, I am seeing is in your statement **H:m** m represents the month, to get the value of minute use **H:i**

```
echo date("H:i \a\\t d/m/Y", $time);
```