# Laravel Valet how to change server timezone

Tags: laravel-valet, valet

I am using laravel valet on macOS as local development environment.
My setup:

- laravel valet
- Nginx
- PHP
- Mysql
- Wordpress (CMS)

**The server default timezone is my machine default timezone.**
I want to set the timezone to be **UTC**. As I want all dates inserted in mysql to be **UTC** as a standard.

I followed [laravel valet docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/valet) for setting up the environment. but noting here is mentioning timezone setup.

When I googled I found this: [How to change the timezone in a Laravel application](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-change-the-timezone-in-a-laravel-application)

Which seems to be related when running a laravel application on valet, not sure if its possible for me to apply it, if yes where can I modify this? as I can't happen to find the correct config file.

Comment: if you're not willing to change via Laravel config, you can also  set the default timezone via the php.ini file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224547/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-php-ini-file